# asp.net gridview search and sort interaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I got a little problem with an asp gridview...

To the gridview i added 2 textboxes and a ddl plus a button in order to search the gridview, which is working properly. here is my code for the search button:

```
 protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string title = TextBoxSearchTitle.Text;
        string artist = TextBoxSearchArtist.Text;
        string genre = DDLSearch.SelectedValue;

        if (genre == "Alle")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = String.Format("Title LIKE '%{0}%' AND Artist LIKE '%{1}%'", title, artist);
        }
        else
        {
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = String.Format("Title LIKE '%{0}%' AND Artist LIKE '%{1}%' AND Genre ='{2}'", title, artist, genre);
        }
    }
```

But now there is a built in sort feature in my gridview, which enables the user to sort the gridview by title or artist. If i now search for a title and get lets say 5 results and after i sort by artist the built in sort feature loads all the items in the sqldatasource to  the gridview where i would rather expect to just sort the results list.

is there a way to fix this?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to overwrite the sorting instead of when you sort garb the original data you need to pass data from your grid currently displayed.

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {      
        DataTable dtSortTable = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

        if (dtSortTable != null)
        {
            DataView dvSortedView = new DataView(dtSortTable);

            dvSortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + "" + getSortDirectionString(e.SortDirection);

            GridView1.DataSource = dvSortedView;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you linked GridView1_Sorting with your grid

Comment: yes i did, else it wouldve thrown an exception i think